# ¿Qué sucede cuando retorno un puntero en una función?

Tags: c++

¿Qué sucede cuando retorno un puntero en una función?... Por ejemplo, si tengo esta función:

```
int *retorno(){
    int *p = new int[1];
    *p = 3;
    return p;
}
```

Y la invoco en el main

```
main(){
    int *f = retorno();
    cout<<*f;
    return 0;
}
```

Si se supone que todas las variables del frame deben desaparecer ¿Por qué en la función main sigo teniendo acceso al contenido de la dirección de memoria retornada?

Comment: La función no es de tipo puntero, la función es de tipo función. Lo que es puntero es el **retorno** de la función.

Comment: Como dice Paper, no puedes decir que una funcion es de tipo puntero, porque eso solo aplica a las variables (una variable puede ser de tipo puntero o no) y una funcion no es una variable. Seria valido, si por ejemplo, dices: *"El tipo de valor de retorno de la funcion es un puntero a `int`"* ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si se supone que todas las variables del frame deben desaparecer

Pues, como tu mismo has dicho, solo desaparecen **las del frame**. Y una zona de memoria obtenida mediante una llamada a `new` **no pertenece al frame** :-)

Hay 4 tipos de variables en C++, basándonos en su *tiempo de vida*:

- Almacenamiento estático: aquellas que pertenecen al ámbito global (fuera de toda función), o aquellas que, aun perteneciendo a una función, se han declarado mediante la palabra reservada `static`.

  Estas variables tienen un tiempo de vida igual **al del propio programa**. Un puntero a una de ellas permanece válido durante todo el tiempo que el programa esté en ejecución.
- Almacenamiento automático: aquellas que pertenecen a una función, y **no** se han declarado mediante `static`.

  Estas variables solo son válidas durante el periodo que tarde en ejecutarse la función. Pasado ese tiempo, su contenido puede ser *destruido* (cambiar a otro contenido aleatorio) en cualquier momento.

  Estas son las variables que tu denominas *de frame*.
- Almacenamiento a nivel de *thread*: aquellas declaradas con el modificador `thread_local`.

  Similares a las variables *automáticas*, pero, en lugar de asociadas a una función, van asociadas a un *hilo* (*thread*). Son válidas desde el inicio del hilo hasta su finalización.
- Almacenamiento dinámico: aquellas que se han obtenido mediante la reserva dinámica de bloques de memoria.

  Estas variables son válidas mientras que el bloque de memoria usado **no sea liberado**. Hay varias formas de reservar estos bloques. En C++, la mas habitual es mediante el uso del `operator new`.

  A esta clase pertenece la dirección que asignas a `p` en tu ejemplo.

Observa que, en los 3 últimos tipos (automáticas, `thread_local` y dinámicas), el valor almacenado en memoria **puede cambiar** en cualquier momento una vez que la variable pierda su validez.

Aquí, el **puede** es *muy mucho* importante. El lenguaje no especifica un momento exacto. Puedes retornar de una función y encontrarte que el valor aun continua allí. O puede que no.